# Console Application written in .NET 5.0 unable to run on colleague's computer

Tags: .net-core, windows-10, console-application, .net-5

I wrote a tool at work in .NET 5.0 that I now have to give to a non-developer to use. Unfortunately, no matter how I publish it I can't get it to run on her computer. Currently I have it set at:

**Configuration:** Release | Any CPU
**Target framework:** net5.0
**Deployment mode:** Self-contained
**Target runtime:** win-x64 (checked that, she definitely has Windows 10 64-bit)

But when she runs it on her PC she gets:

```
Failed to load the dll from [C:\Users\username\Desktop\Release Builder\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from C:\Users\username\Desktop\Release Builder\hostfxr.dll failed
  - Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=798306
```

I, of course, checked the link and she has above the minimum version of Windows 10. What gives? I'm use to either building web applications or just building console tools for myself. I figured self-contained would mean just handing over the contents of the publish folder.

I should point out, that the publish folder APPEARS to be correct... its over 230 files in there.

Comment: check if the [settings are correct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#publish-a-single-file-app---sample-project-file)

Comment: The project XML matches what I said above (which I see now I should reformat so it's easier to read)

Comment: I posted a solution. It is working for me. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to publish with these settings?

Step 1:

[image: publish settings]

Step 2: Open your `.csproj` and add these, or swap with yours.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    // keep other info
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I've tried single file.... haven't done ReadyToRun. I'll see if I can get into her computer this afternoon and if that fixes it, I'll pop back over here and let you know!

Comment: It was Enable ReadyToRun compilation. That fixed it!

Comment: Thanks so much! Not sure why I didn't try "ReadyToRun" to begin with, as in hindsight the name kind of implies it makes it ready to run...